# Why do dupe questions automatically redirect when logged out?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

When logged out, why do dupe questions redirect?

E.g.,

*[How do I commit all deleted files in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402776)*

automatically redirects to:

*[Removing multiple files from a Git repo that have already been deleted from disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492558)*

Redirection doesn't occur when logged in.

Answer (score 11):

For users who are not logged in, posts having no answer and closed as a duplicate are auto-redirected to the original post. So [How do I commit all deleted files in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402776) takes you to [Removing multiple files from a Git repo that have already been deleted from disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492558).

> [image]

---

**What reasoning is behind this?**

It was implemented based on [this feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125220/automatically-redirect-anonymous-user-from-unanswered-duplicate-question-to-corr):

> the user experience when an anonymous user arrives at a duplicate is less than ideal.
>
> They have to notice the duplicate link and understand that the answer they are looking for is likely behind that link. I don't think this is all that obvious to someone without experience with an SE site.

On the answer from Kevin Montrose it is explained how to disable this behavior:

> As with migration and merge redirects you can disable by adding  `?noredirect=1` to the url