# Should I reopen a low quality question which I closed as a duplicate of a wrong question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer, question-quality

Recently I dupehammered the question [JS How to get text of child button elements with a div with a known ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40834104/3853934). I incorrectly used [jQuery to loop through elements with the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4735342/3853934) as the duplicate target, because I thought there was an issue with looping over the elements. When I realized that I dupehammered it wrongly, I didn't reopen it, because it's a very low quality question (the answer is easily googlable) and anyway it was a duplicate of [Use jQuery to get text of target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14720807/3853934). However, another user with a gold JavaScript tag badge (who is also a moderator) reopened it and told me that what I did was wrong. Here's what they wrote in a comment:

> Leaving a question closed as a duplicate of an irrelevant question *because it is a in fact a duplicate of [Use jQuery to get text of target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720807/use-jquery-to-get-text-of-target)* just doesn't make sense. The correct thing to do is to re-open the question, then vote-to-close it as a duplicate of the correct question. Whether you feel this question is poor or not it is irrelevant; questions should be closed as duplicates when they are duplicates, not because you think they are poor quality.

I don't quite agree with that. If I reopened that question, I wouldn't be able to use my dupehammer again to close it, so it could take some time to get closed again, or it could never get closed at all. I realize that leaving a question closed as a duplicate of an irrelevant question is bad, but IMO leaving a low quality question opened is worse.

As for "you think they are poor quality": it's not only me, it's also 4 other people who downvoted that question.

Comment: That is not what Spolsky wants you to do.  Just don't overthink it, apply reverse reasoning.  Pick "too broad" when the question is too localized and "unclear what you're asking" when you know exactly what's he's asking and don't give a hoot for it.

Comment: Yeah, don't use the dupe hammer to close crap questions against inappropriate targets.  They end up being bad signposts, which is not what dupes are supposed to be. We love our dupe hammers, and what SE may give, SE may take.

Comment: @Will It sounds like it was simply a mistake; the user *though* that it was a good dupe target when they cast the vote, and later realized it wasn't an applicable duplicate, but could no longer cast a close vote for the *proper* duplicate target.

Comment: IIRC (from years ago, and this may be different for wielders of the golden hammer anyway), you cannot (vote to) close a question after you (voted to) reopen anyway?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz That is correct, as Gothdo mentions in the question.  The commenter who suggested otherwise was incorrect.

Comment: @Servy I'm pretty sure I have done that. I think the rule is that you can only vote to close it once and only vote to open it once. But it doesn't matter the order?

Comment: @MartinSmith: I think that's right.  So you can reopen + duphammer a question if you didn't already close it.  Also, if you initially VTC as too broad, missing MCVE, or whatever, but then find a duplicate, you're out of luck.  That last bit is what I think is a bit silly, since putting a question on hold until the OP clarifies is the right action, and then dup-hammering is the right action.  It does mean you can't be lazy and cast other close votes instead of doing the searching now to find the dup-target you vaguely remember seeing.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, but he had already voted to close it, so he wouldn't be able to close it again after reopening it.

Answer (score 27):

> When I realized that I dupehammered it wrongly, I didn't reopen it, because it's a very low quality question (the answer is easily googlable)...

This is the part of your response I still don't understand. Closing a question as a duplicate helps two types of people;

1. The OP
2. Other people who come across the question.

By closing the question as a duplicate of a wholly irrelevant question, then failing to re-open it *because it is very low quality* does not help *either* the OP or other users. Worse, closing the question prevents other users from submitting answers, which means instead of *helping* users, you are actively **preventing** users from getting help.

---

> ... and anyway it was a duplicate of [Use jQuery to get text of target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14720807/3853934)

Whilst it's great **you** knew the question was a duplicate of [Use jQuery to get text of target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14720807/3853934), you didn't articulate this in *any* fashion (comment or otherwise) to the OP.

The OP asked a question. You closed the question as a duplicate of an irrelevant question, then disappeared into the distance never to be seen again. He (and future visitors to the question) had **no** idea that other duplicate existed on the site.

Even if you *had* linked to the correct duplicate via comment or similar, this is still non-optimal. The system has checks in place to prevent questions which are dupe-targets from being deleted, and will automatically redirect to dupe targets in [certain situations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271077/why-do-dupe-questions-automatically-redirect-when-logged-out). Abusing duplicates in the fashion outlined here bypasses, breaks, and confuses all of this.

Comment: Your answer is based on a false premise there will actually be some people that come across the question. The whole point is that people Googling "get text of element using jquery" will get straight to the jQuery documentation. This question won't serve as a signpost—it's the bad kind of duplicate questions and should be deleted.

Comment: @Gothdo: and what about helping the OP? I made him a pretty main part of my answer.

Comment: Honestly, I don't feel like helping someone who is wasting my time by asking a question with an easily Googlable solution. I think that linking to the correct duplicate in a comment would be enough.

Comment: @Gothdo If you don't feel like helping, don't help, just stay out of it entirely. You could have just downvoted the question and moved on. But once you take action, and that action turns out wrong, you should be ready to clean up your own mess. It's a basic matter of taking responsibility for your actions.

Comment: @Gothdo: I have to agree with hvd on this.  I don't think posters of terrible "didn't even google" questions deserve any help, esp. in a case where you say the right "answer" would just be a comment pointing to the right part of the official docs.  But leaving a question closed as a wrong duplicate pollutes the dup-target's linked-questions list, and is just all-around so bad that you need to undo it and remember not to be so hasty next time.  I've occasionally had to reopen a post I hammered after realizing I had made a mistake, and it sucks, but it's the right action.

Answer (score 13):

Had you not linked the real duplicate in comments I might care, and would probably consider the behavior inappropriate, but considering you specifically mentioned the real duplicate in comments, thereby allowing the next mjolner holder to come along and fix the problem, I don't see it as an issue.  Anyone actually looking for the solution to the problem can still get it, they just have to read a little further along until the question gets fixed than they otherwise would have.

I have much more of a problem with the user that reopened the question *and then didn't immediately re-close it when they knew there was an applicable duplicate*.  Fixing the dupe target is fine, but leaving the known-duplicate question open isn't appropriate.

Comment: Gothdo mentioned the duplicate *after* being called out by Matt. He admitted that he knew *before* being called out that the duplicate was incorrect, and what the correct duplicate was, but neglected to inform the OP of that.

Comment: @TinyGiant What makes you say he knew it was wrong *before* Matt pointed it out?  It looks like it was when Matt pointed it out that he then realized he was wrong.

Comment: I guess that's a subjective conclusion drawn from this sentence in the OP: *"I didn't reopen it, ... and anyway it was a duplicate of [Use jQuery to get text of target]"* and how that comes *before* *"However, another user with a gold JavaScript tag badge (who is also a moderator) reopened it and told me that what I did was wrong."* in Gothdo's statement of events

Comment: @TinyGiant I suspect the order of events what Matt commented asking why the given duplicate was chosen, Gothdo then realized his mistake, said as much, and indicated the superior dup target, and then Matt replied to that, chastising him for not reopening the question when he acknowledged his mistake.  That would be consistent with the sequencing you brought up.  I agree we can't know for sure if Gothdo realized his mistake before he said as much; he could clarify if he wanted to.  I'm willing to give him the benefit of the doubt until I have reason to believe otherwise though.

Comment: @Servy _"I have much more of a problem with the user that reopened the question and then didn't immediately re-close it when they knew there was an applicable duplicate. Fixing the dupe target is fine, but leaving the known-duplicate question open isn't appropriate."_ See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082643/can-i-declare-an-array-of-values-that-are-nested-inside-a-collection-of-objects/

Comment: @guest271314 I fail to see how that question is related to that quote.

Comment: @Servy Voted to and closed the newest Question. The newest Question was reopened by another user. From perspective, here, the former and latter Question and Answers are identical. Posted same Answer at newest Question to illustrate that fact. Every individual user has their own interpretation of the actual text at a Question. Perhaps from your perspective the two questions and answers are sufficiently distinct enough to not warrant closing the newest Question as a duplicate of the previous Question. There is, apparently, no objective standard for determining if a Question is a duplicate?

Comment: @guest271314 The user that reopened it is at least asserting that the question shouldn't be reopened.  I didn't really look to closely at the questions, so I'm not really commenting on whether or not the questions are duplicates, but at least the person that reopened the questions honestly thinks the question isn't a duplicate.  That's different than someone reopening a question (and not re-closing it) *when they know full well it's a duplicate*, which I find far worse.  I can respect someone who honestly disagrees, but someone who knows the question merits closure and doesn't care...

Answer (score 5):

I'd say **yes**, because questions closed as duplicates will not get roomba'd. Reopening it allows it to be closed as something else that allows for the question to be automatically deleted.

Comment: Also, in some circumstances (I don't know the circumstances) duplicates accessed from google will automatically redirect to the target. This would be really confusing if the target is incorrect.

Comment: If the post is downvoted, it's probably best **not** to dupehammer it at all if you want it to be deleted - if no-one answers in 30 days and the score is less than or equal to -1, it gets eaten by the Roomba anyway.

Comment: @TinyGiant I think that's the case when the user doesn't have an account on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Aurora0001 Not exactly, duplicate questions, in fact any (unlocked) questions, are roombad after 30 days of asking, if they are negatively scored without answers. See `RemoveDeadQuestions` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed as "something else"—it's not too broad, POB, unclear or off-topic. It should be closed as a duplicate of [Use jQuery to get text of target](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14720807/3853934). Also, duplicate questions which has negative score and no answers are roomba'd too (`RemoveDeadQuestions`).

Comment: @Tunaki good point - I assumed for some reason that `RemoveDeadQuestions` left duplicates alone. So, tl;dr is that it doesn't really matter, it'll be removed either way then, I'd say.

Comment: @TinyGiant I doubt that this question will ever be accessed from Google, because when you Google "get text of element using jquery", the first result is jQuery documentation. Also the circumstances are as follows: question has no answers and the user visiting the question is anonymous (not logged in).

Comment: @Aurora0001 an under 10k view of things [here](http://i.imgur.com/ZwyR6K5.jpg). It had no answers and was at -3. So it is the first Saturday early morning that the roomba script and its [rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) runs into those questions *AND* the script succeeds. That is, it has endured several weekends of bombing out. Perhaps they fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

> The correct thing to do is to re-open the question, then vote-to-close it as a duplicate of the correct question.

It's a slightly different topic, but [Shog's answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295316/abuse-of-duplicate-marking/295317#295317) is highly relevant to this discussion (emphasis mine)

> Assuming the questions are actually duplicates, then no it isn't abuse because marking duplicates is exactly what this feature is for. Yes, there's some additional motivation for dup-closing in favor of your own answers - that too is intentional, since there's already a considerable amount of motivation to be had in just re-answering duplicates if your only goal is to garner rep. **Closing reduces duplication of answers**, so a bit of extra motivation for answerers to write re-usable answers instead of dozens of bespoke replies is to everyone's benefit.
>
> **You can disagree about which question should be the target, but that doesn't change anything** - and when in doubt, picking the older question is a quite reasonable default.

So, no, you shouldn't JUST reopen to hammer it to a better question. **It's a duplicate either way.** Linking the correct dupe in comments is perfectly acceptable. If the other gold badge wants to do that, he can. You can't because you've already voted to close it. You should only reopen it if it is proven it's not a duplicate.

Comment: The point is the original dupe target was *not* an actual duplicate. The text you are quoting describes a situation where there are multiple possible dupe targets that are *actual* duplicates of the question. In the case where there are multiple *actual* duplicates, then which is used is less important. In this case, where the dupe target originally chosen was *not* an actual duplicate, Gothdo should have re-opened the question and voted to close as a duplicate of the correct dupe target and left a comment explaining the situation. IMO, to do otherwise is an abuse of the dupe hammer.

Comment: @Makyen You contradicted yourself. `was not an actual duplicate` and `Gothdo should have re-opened the question and voted to close as a duplicate of the correct dupe target`. Is it a dupe or isn't it? The point I'm making is that if the dupe target is wrong, **it's still a dupe** and the target is not as important.

Comment: We clearly don't read what I wrote the same. "was not an actual duplicate" is referring to the original target of the dupe close, of which the closed question is *not* a duplicate. Whereas "voted to close as a duplicate of the correct dupe target" is referring to a dupe target which is an *actual* duplicate of the question (possibly one of many *actual* duplicates). I *strongly* disagree with your reasoning that it is more important to dupe-close a question to any random question than it is that the target of the dupe-close be an *actual* duplicate of the question. (continued)

Comment: (continued) This is also *not* what the answer you are quoting says. It says "Assuming the questions are actually duplicates". Analogy: You are arguing that "What color are apples?" should be closed to "Oranges are orange." Whereas, the answer you are quoting is that arguing that what doesn't matter is if the "What color are apples?" question is closed to one that is answered "Many apples are red with other colors possible", vs. one saying "Some apples are red while others are green", regardless of if the person wielding the dupe hammer wrote the answer on the one they are using as the target.

Comment: @Makyen I am arguing nothing of the sort. What I'm saying is that if you have "What color are apples?" and you misread it and close it as a dupe of "What color are apes?", there are logistical problems in reopening it just to get it reclosed as a dupe of "Can apples have colors beyond red?". The original hammer cannot re-hammer it and, in the meantime, it get all sorts of dupe answers. It would be simpler, in that case, to just vote to delete the dupe and leave a comment to the real dupe. Re-opening and re-closing to correct a dupe target is generally a waste of time.

Comment: I don't see how your clarification that you are arguing that closing it as a duplicate of "What color are apes?" is any different than closing it as a duplicate to the question implied by the answer "Oranges are orange". Your comment appears to confirm my understanding that you are arguing that closing it as a dupe of *any random question* is *significantly* more important than that the dupe-target be an *actual* duplicate of the question. We **significantly** disagree. IMO, one of the reasons the dupe-hammer power is given is that such people are trusted to *not do* what you are advocating.

Comment: I view using the dupe-hammer power as you are advocating (close to any random question) as directly violating the trust implicit in being granted the dupe-hammer power. IMO, someone with that power who encounters a question that is dupe-targeted to a question which is not an *actual* duplicate has the obligating to open the question and re-hammer it to an *actual* duplicate. Someone who realizes they have hammered to a non-duplicate has an obligation to re-open the question and move the question as far as possible in the direction of being closed with an *actual* duplicate as the dupe-target.

Comment: "You should only reopen it if it is proven it's not a duplicate." -- Whether it's worth re-opening and closing properly when there's already a link in the comments is something I can see both points of view on (though I'd still disagree), but this, what the hell? Do you have any idea how many questions SO has? The suggestion that you don't have to even bother finding a proper dupe target, that it's up to the poster to prove that the question hasn't been asked before when the only way to prove that is by going through each and every one, is completely and utterly absurd.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the same boat quite often.

Of course, the best solution would be either

- to let a *trusted user* correct their mistake by allowing them to close twice.
- or to let a *trusted user* singlehandedly close a low quality question.

but there is a constant fear for an abuse and thus nobody's trusted. So in your place I would keep them closed. There are millions of crappy questions on SO and making a fuss over yet another one makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0):

> If I reopened that question, I wouldn't be able to use my dupehammer again to close it, so it could take some time to get closed again, or it could never get closed at all.

That is a fact of life 'round these parts. You could always come to meta or hop into chat and ask others to help close it correctly.

> I realize that leaving a question closed as a duplicate of an irrelevant question is bad, but IMO leaving a low quality question opened is worse.

Well, is the question off-topic?

I realize that low quality questions are bad, but if it isn't off-topic does it really need to be closed that bad?

We don't close questions solely because they are low quality, show a lack of research effort, or are not useful. That is what downvotes are for.

---

Google generates the most amount of traffic of any source for Stack Overflow.

Duplicate closures help direct users reaching the question from Google.

In some circumstances, users reaching the question from Google will be automatically redirected to the target question.

**If the target won't help googlers, then it is detrimental to the site.**

Comment: But googlers won't find it. Googlers will get straight to jQuery documentation.

Comment: @Gothdo I was speaking to the general situation, so that this would be useful for future readers, not necessarily to this specific question. Are you implying that the title and body of the question will never be relevant to a Google search query?

Comment: Yes. This question is not a good signpost question.

Comment: So you're saying that it is impossible that anyone would ever enter a search query the could possibly result in a reference to the question in question?

Comment: Not impossible, but very unlikely. Are you implying that we should never delete duplicate questions?

Comment: However unlikely it may be, we should account for that. But seriously, why is the target question not closed as a typo? He's missing the parenthesis, pretty darn simple typo.

Answer (score 0):

You have said in a few places

> But googlers won't find it. Googlers will get straight to jQuery documentation

However I disagree. I give SO hits equal or better goodwill when I am searching for something in Google. This is because vendor documentation is almost always lagging behind the product and canny vendors also keep an eye on SO questions related to their products so you often get a better time-to-answer outcome with SO. That's what makes it so valuable.

Comment: "vendor documentation is almost always lagging behind the product" Exactly, *almost*. jQuery documentation is very good.

Comment: I can't make the assumption that the OP has that measure of experience given the quality of the question. But again your experience of the JQ docs is subjective.