# Stop redirecting from duplicates when the target is deleted

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions, anonymous-user

It's well-known that for logged-out users, duplicate questions with no answers redirect to their duplicate target (see [Why do links to duplicate question automatically redirect to the duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285853/7509065) and [Why do dupe questions automatically redirect when logged out?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271077/7509065)). I've found an edge case where this shouldn't happen, though:

Consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56430407/7509065). It's been marked as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56385618/7509065). The dupe still exists (for now), but the target has been deleted. If a logged-out user visits the former link, they'll be shown the "Page not found" message, which is certainly not more useful than being shown the still-extant duplicate. In cases like this, shouldn't we instead just show them the duplicate, rather than sending them to an even less useful page?

(Credit to [Laurel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6083675/laurel) for pointing me to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/169338/find-duplicates-of-deleted-posts), to find a new example after my original was broken.)

Comment: I thought deletion wasn't supposed to be possible if the question was a duplicate target...

Comment: @TinyGiant The auto-delete system still doesn't pay attention to that criteria.

Comment: Try [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/169338/find-duplicates-of-deleted-posts). With it, you can find many other duplicates of deleted questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56430407).

Comment: Lil' note: This does not only apply to logged-out users; it's also goes for logged-in users <10k.

Comment: @geisterfurz007: I've never seen this behavior while logged-in.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 They are talking about redirects not the ability to see deleted questions, logged in users do not get force redirected to the duplicate target.

Comment: Oooooooooooh! Sorry; I didn't even know that was a thing. Thanks for clarifying :) Yeah I just read the first paragraph again... I must have missed that ^^"

Comment: [Here's a somewhat fancier version](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209965/duplicates-of-deleted-questions) of @Laurel's query. (Unfortunately it's also somewhat slower, mostly because it does a series of rather inefficient cross-site queries to filter out duplicates of migrated questions.)

Comment: I would argue that this is not a well-known fact: I've been here for years, and never heard about it! (And I lurk in meta pretty frequently). This is not really important for the point in the question, though.

Comment: @animuson isn't that something that should be addressed? Considering the question in example right now, having it marked as duplicate is pretty useless if the target is deleted.

Comment: How did that dupe ever get created? The dupe target has no answers.

Comment: @Joshua Because the same person asked both the duplicate and the target.

Comment: Redirecting seems like a dumb idea to begin with. Wouldn't be surprised if it hurts SEO.

Comment: [Does SO care about logged out users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386505/new-home-page-makes-it-seem-like-so-doesnt-allow-free-use-any-more)?. On a more serious note. This needs to be fixed :)

Comment: @Joshua A dupe target doesn't need answers when the same users asks the same question multiple times. That's also not a new rule.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of today, anonymous visits to unanswered duplicates where all targets have been deleted will no longer redirect. There are currently 21 such questions on Stack Overflow.

Along with this change, anonymous visits to unanswered duplicates with *multiple* targets where all but one are deleted now *will*  redirect to the sole remaining undeleted original. There are currently 35 such questions on Stack Overflow.

TODO: [figure out what to do with duplicates when their target(s) are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169197/does-duplicate-marking-go-away-once-original-is-deleted). There are currently 800-some such questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are they all from the same user like this one?